# Enabling athreos 9k to run at 5 GHz channel

Tags: linux-device-driver

I want to run setup an AP in the 5GHz channel in 802.11n mode. I can currently run it in the 2.4GHz range by setting up the hostapd.conf file as such:

```
driver=nl80211
interface=wlan1
ssid=xxxxx
channel=9
hw_mode=g
auth_algs=1
ieee80211n=1
wme_enabled=1
wmm_enabled=1
ht_capab=[TX-STBC][RX-STBC]
```

I have tried changing hw_mode to a and using the channel as 36, 40, 44, 149, 153 and other ones available in North America.

Everytime is simply says "Configured channel(36) not found from the channel list of current mode(2) IEEE 802.11a.

Is there a way to set it in the 5GHz range?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have regulatory domain database?